# Is DBus only meant for IPC

Tags: dbus

I am investigating on DBus message Q. Just a few queries:
1) Does DBus guarantees messages to be ordered( FIFO ) ?
2) Can DBus be used for Distributed System( processes lying in different systems )

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, message order is preserved, though different senders may race.  There are some D-Bus libraries that mess up the order to implement synchronous method calls.

2) No / sort-off. D-Bus most commonly is implemented on top of UNIX domain sockets, that are by definition limited to one host.  D-Bus specification allows D-Bus to be ran on top of TCP.  Thus one node can work as a messaging hub.  So, not really distributed.

Also, many D-Bus libraries don't allow contacting arbitrary busses (if "connect" call only supports "system" and "session", those refer to the two default UNIX domain socket on Linux systems)

Answer (score -1):

1) No, sender sets (arbitrary) message serial number and it's other side responsibility to set same number in reply serial field

2) Yes, as long as your bus daemon able to understand nodes location from service name and route messages accordingly. Not sure about `dbus-daemon` capabilities

Comment: 1) That’s misleading. The `dbus-daemon` guarantees never to re-order messages, so they are always forwarded to peers in the order they were received from the sender. That’s FIFO. The reply serial field allows message replies to be matched by the recipient if the sender replies to two messages out of order.

2) Vague. There’s no concept of a ‘node’ in D-Bus. The `dbus-daemon` operates in terms of connections to it. If some of those connections are via TCP (as Anonymous says), then D-Bus can be considered a distributed system on a network. In general, D-Bus is a distributed process system.

Comment: looks like I misunderstood "ordered"  (wow, 5 years ago!). My reply was to the question "Can I rely on the fact that message serial goes continuously 1,2,3,4,5,6,...?"

Comment: > can you point to the spec where 1) is explained?
It’s not mentioned in the spec, but having discussed with the D-Bus maintainer, it’s definitely a guarantee of dbus-daemon (the reference daemon implementation) and is sufficiently entrenched that he would consider any other implementation which *doesn’t* provide the same ordering guarantees as broken. I’ve filed https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101563 about this.